# Gridview wrap content flutter

Tags: flutter, gridview

I have a json, I want to display it in gridview, the json has many content, in gridview I just want to show only 9 items.

The problem was I want to wrap the content of the gridview but I dont know how. 
I tried wrap widget. If its not possible then I guess I'll reconsider using columns and row for this one.

Please check the code below.

[image]

```
class ServicesWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _ServicesState createState() => _ServicesState();
}

class _ServicesState extends State<ServicesWidget> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Flexible(
      child: GridView.count(
        crossAxisCount: 3,
        childAspectRatio: 1,
        children: <Widget>[
          Center(child: Text('qwe')),
          Center(child: Text('qwe')),
          Center(child: Text('qwe')),
          Center(child: Text('qwe')),
          Center(child: Text('qwe')),
          Center(child: Text('qwe')),
          Center(child: Text('qwe')),
          Center(child: Text('qwe')),
          Center(child: Text('qwe')),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

```
class HomeScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _HomeState createState() => _HomeState();
}

class _HomeState extends State<HomeScreen> {

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return DirectSelectContainer(
      child: Scaffold(
          appBar: AppBar(
            title: Row(
              children: <Widget>[
                // cityDirectSelect(),
                // areaDirectSelect(),
                Spacer(flex: 1),
                IconButton(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.all(0),
                  icon: Icon(Icons.person),
                  color: Colors.grey,
                  onPressed: () {
                    Get.off(LoginScreen());
                  },
                )
              ],
            ),
          ),
          body: Center(
            child: Container(
              child: Column(
                children: <Widget>[
                  ServicesWidget(),
                  Container(
                    width: double.infinity,
                    child: Text('qweqwe'),
                    color: Colors.red,
                  )
                ],
              ),
            ),
          )),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "wrap"?

Comment: Since the children of the gridview was fixed, I want to achieve a gridview that the height can wrap content.

Comment: Wrap with what?

Comment: Like the  wrap_content of android

Comment: Please be more descriptive. I am not an android developer.

Comment: @ChristopherMoore he means that gridview items are squares, but he wants them to "wrap the content", so the item height doesn't have an overflow when there is too much content. I'm facing the same issue

Answer (score 2):

I solve it using shrinkWrap. Now the gridview height is wrapped according to its children.[shrinkwrap gridview](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/GridView/shrinkWrap.html)